# How to insert a parameter in a function that is inside other functions in Kotlin

Tags: firebase, function, kotlin, high-order-component

I have a function which receives a MutableList parameter, which is inside other functions. But this last function does not accept it.

```
ObtenerUsuarios{ :Adaptador{::LecturaFacturas{::createRecyclerViewA(listdeClientsString) }}}
```

When I insert the parameter in createRecyclerViewA it says :this sintax is reserverd for future use...

```
    fun crearRecyclerViewA(ListDatosX: MutableList<String>){

    var adapter = RecyclerAdapter(ListDatosX)
    recyclerA.adapter=adapter

    adapter.setOnClickListener {
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "${ListDatos.get(recycler.getChildAdapterPosition(it))}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() //
        var posicion :Int =recyclerA.getChildAdapterPosition(it)
         println("$posicion +  esta es la variable posicion")
        VerEnPantalla(posicion) // Despliega opciones para realizar aprobar pago
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`::createRecyclerViewA` isn't a function call, it's a *function reference* - a way of referring to a function as a thing you can pass around. You can't add `()` onto the end - if you want to call the function, you have to use `invoke(params)` on the reference

```
::createRecyclerViewA.invoke(listdeClientsString)
```

I don't know why you want to do that if you're invoking it right there - just call the function normally, `createRecyclerViewA(listdeClientsString)`. But if you *are* passing function references around, that's how you invoke them

Comment: Since I have many calls to databases and they have to be ordered! Thanks a lot!